# Python program or sql code to assign a group number to similar columns in a table

Tags: python, sql, pandas, group-by, apache-spark-sql

I have the input in the following format. I wanted to assign a group number to mapped Col A to ColB. For example if you consider 222 in COL A, which is pointing to 111  and 112 in Col B, I want all the three numbers to be assigned to same group number.
Please help me with this. Thanks in advance

[image]
[image]

Comment: What would happen if 114 was 112? Would all values now be in the same group?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with *Sql Server*, but I looked at *Spark* to make sure they have the same functions so it should work for you as is.

```
with t2 as (
           select colA, colB
           from   t

           union all 
  
           select distinct colA, colA
           from   t
           )

select     dense_rank() over(order by colA) as grpnumber
          ,colB                             as ID
from       t2
```

| grpnumber | ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 111 |
| 1 | 112 |
| 1 | 222 |
| 2 | 114 |
| 2 | 115 |
| 2 | 333 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DOMrrxCU?hide=2)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `factorize` to create the group and `melt` to reshape:

```
out = (df
   .assign(grpnumber=pd.factorize(df['colA'])[0]+1)
   .melt('grpnumber', value_name='ID')
   .drop_duplicates()
   .sort_values(by='grpnumber', ignore_index=True)
   .drop(columns='variable')
 )
```

Output:

```
   grpnumber   ID
0          1  222
1          1  111
2          1  112
3          2  333
4          2  114
5          2  115
```

Answer (score 0):

Check Below code using **PANDAS**

```
import pandas as pd 

def list_series(val):
  return list(val)

df = df.groupby(['COL A']).agg(GRP_COL_B=('COL B',list_series)).reset_index()

df['ID'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['GRP_COL_B']+[x['COL A']], axis=1)

df['grpnumber'] = df.index+1

df[['ID','grpnumber']].explode('ID')
```

Output:

[image]